# Running a non bat extension file as a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, portability

Let's say I have a text file, it contains batch commands. How can I run that text file as a batch file from within one, **without** renaming it. I want too keep a portable aspect too it, so no registry keys or such.

The reason for no renaming is too prevent leftover unrenamed files upon unexpected closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
type some.txt>temp.bat
call temp.bat
del /q /f temp.bat
```

Is  creating a temp file cheating?It's not mentioned as restriction in the question.Though you can loose the `%ERRORLEVEL%` because of the del command , but you can keep it in temp variable:

```
type some.txt>temp.bat
call temp.bat
set temp_el=%errorlevel%
del /q /f temp.bat
exit /b %temp_el%
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is this:

```
cmd < file.txt
```

As in the previous answers, there are several commands that will not work in this file, like `GOTO`, `SETLOCAL` and others. However, multiline nested `if` and `for` commands *do* work as long as for replaceable parameters use just one percent (like in the command-line).

Although this method alaways show in the screen the executed commands (`@echo off` not works here), you may redirect the output to NUL and in the "Batch" file redirect the desired output to CON. For example, this is **test.txt**:

```
@echo off
echo Hello World! > CON

(for /L %a in (1,1,10) do (
   echo Turn: %a
   if %a equ 4 echo TURN NUMBER FOUR!
)) > CON
```

Output example:

```
C:\> cmd < test.txt > NUL
Hello World!
Turn: 1
Turn: 2
Turn: 3
Turn: 4
TURN NUMBER FOUR!
Turn: 5
Turn: 6
Turn: 7
Turn: 8
Turn: 9
Turn: 10
```

Comment: Further details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320578/how-to-run-batch-script-with-out-using-bat-extention/13337597#13337597

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you cannot do what you want. Windows will not let you configure the OS to recognize any other extensions as batch files. Only `.bat` and `.cmd` are supported.

You could process a series of simple commands within a text file using a FOR /F loop, but it will be very restrictive. For example, it will not support `IF`, `FOR`, `GOTO Label`, or `CALL :Label`. There are probably other restrictions. Within your main batch file, you could have the following:

```
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%A in (script.txt) do %%A
```

You might be able to support `IF` and/or `FOR` if you execute the command via a new CMD.EXE shell, but then you cannot preserve the value of variables that might be SET by the command.

```
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%A in (script.txt) do cmd /c "%%A"
```

Comment: Since it can't be done, is there a more efficient way of renaming then? I.e temp or such?

Comment: the `set` can be "saved" by putting everything in one variable and separating commands with `&`.But with big files will not work because of the variable length limit.And the brackets could cause a problem.

Comment: I always renamed it, called it, renamed it again. I did it using Ren. example `ren C:\users\Jared\runMe.txt runMe.bat`

Answer (score 1):

See the windows shell commands

- `assoc`. Associates a filename extension (e.g. *.txt) with a file type.
- `ftype`. Lets you create a new file type that tells the windows shell how to open a particular kind of file.

From a command prompt, typing `assoc /?` or `ftype /?` will get you help on them. Or use your google-fu to find the MS docs.

`*.bat` is mapped to the file type `batfile`; `*.cmd` is mapped to the file type `cmdfile`. In windows 7 they are identical. If you want to be able to run files named `*.foobar` as a batch files, just type:

```
assoc .foobar=cmdfile
```

Then, assuming a file named 'sillyness.foobar' existing on the path, you just just type

```
c:\> sillyness
```

and it will find `sillyness.foobar` and execute it as a batch file. The Windows shell has a priority for how it resolves conflicts when you have files with the same name and different extensions (.com vs .cmd vs .bat, etc.)

Something like

```
assoc .pl=perlscript
ftype perlscript=perl.exe %1 %*
```

will set you up to run perl scripts as if they were .bat files.

Comment: It just spawns a new cmd instance.

Answer (score 0):

If your batch commands are simple sequential ones then you could use this at the command prompt.  Double the `%` signs for use in a batch file.

```
for /f "delims=" %a in (file.txt) do %a
```