# How to DIRECTLY execute command in txt file in cmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

I have a question.

> How can I execute command in a plain text file?

I know it seems crazy and I can simply rename it as a .bat file BUT it is important for me.
Without renaming it, can i execute it in CMD?

I know I can simply do this :

```
ren command.txt command.bat & call command.bat & ren command.bat command.txt
```

But this is too inconvenient. Any simpler way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
cmd < command.txt
```

Of course it depends of the real content of command.txt.

Comment: Good enough. Didn't thought of that.

Comment: You may even execute `if` and `for %a` commands in the text file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242301/running-a-non-bat-extension-file-as-a-batch-file/21248399#21248399

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%* IN (command.txt) DO %%*
```