# Batch file: Reading and activate commands from unknown files

Tags: batch-file, console, command

I know the title doesn't make sense, but I have one question. I have made this file called Test.bin and here's whats inside the .bin file:

echo Hello World

Since its a test file, I've been trying to see if i can make a batch file that can read the commands in the .bin file and output it onto the console.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to do exactly, but I think you have two options:

Rename test.bin as test.bat and run it with:

```
test
```

Start a new command interpreter and send it your commands:

```
cmd < test.bin
```

Comment: I have used the cmd < Test.bin string and it did what i wanted. Thank you Mark Setchell for the help! Now I need to play with it to get the program to work.

Comment: I suggest you to see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320578/how-to-run-batch-script-with-out-using-bat-extention/13337597#13337597

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the copy command. However, for this to work the test.bin file should be
in the same directory/folder. Alternatively, you can specify the file's path.

Your code should look something like this:

```
@echo off
copy test.bin
```

Or, using the filepath method (pretending its on your desktop):

```
@echo off
copy C:/users/me/Desktop/test.bin
```