# C++ regex segfault on long sequences

Tags: c++, regex, gcc, clang, c++14

I was parsing stackoverflow dump and came up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23860361/batch-file-reading-and-activate-commands-from-unknown-files) seemingly innocent question with small, almost invisible detail that it has 22311 spaces at the end of text.

I'm using std::regex (somehow they work better for me than boost::regex) to replace all continuous whitespaces with single space like this:

```
std::regex space_regex("\\s+", std::regex::optimize);
...
std::regex_replace(out, in, in + strlen(in), space_regex, " ");
```

SIGSEGV shows up and I have begun to investigate.

Test code:

```
#include <regex>
...
std::regex r("\\s+",  std::regex::optimize);
const char* bomb2 = "Small text\n\nwith several\n\nlines.";
std::string test(bomb2);
for (auto i = 0; i < N; ++i) test += " ";

std::string out = std::regex_replace(test.c_str(), r, " ");
std::cout << out << std::endl;
```

for (gcc 5.3.0)

```
$ g++ -O3 -std=c++14 regex-test.cpp -o regex-test.out
```

maximum `N` before SIGSEGV shows up is 21818 (for this particular string), and for

```
$ g++ -O0 -std=c++14 regex-test.cpp -o regex-test.out
```

it's 12180.

'Ok, let's try clang, it's trending and aims to replace gcc' - never have I been so wrong. With `-O0` clang (v. 3.7.1) crashes on 9696 spaces - less then gcc, but not much, yet with `-O3` and even with `-O2` it crashes on ZERO spaces.

Crash dump presents huge stacktraces (35k frames) of recursive calls of

```
std::__detail::_Executor<char*, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::sub_match<char*> >, std::__cxx11::regex_traits<char>, true>::_M_dfs
```

**Question 1**: Is this a bug? If so, should I report it?

**Question 2**: Is there smart way to overcome the problem (other than increasing system stack size, trying other regex libraries and writing own function to replace whitespaces)?

---

**Amendment:** [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70459) created for libstdc++

Comment: Your  test code [works correctly with clang if the compiler option -stdlib=libc++ is used](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91ffcf96e925b2a3). Likely to be a bug of libstdc++.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Is this a bug? If so, should I report it?

Yes this is a bug.

```
cout << '"' << regex_replace("Small text\n\nwith several\n\nlines." + string(22311, ' '), regex("\\s+", regex::optimize), " ") << '"' << endl;
```

- Runs fine with libc++: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9ee5438745a5b22
- Runs fine with Visual Studio 2015, you can test by copying  and running the code at: http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/
- Fails with libstdc++: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f4bbe5c46b6b627

This has been bugged in libstdc++ [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61582).

## Is there smart way to overcome the problem?

If you're asking for a new `regex` that works, I've tried a handful of different versions, and all of them fail on libstdc++, so I'd say, if you want to use a `regex` to solve this, you'll need to compile against libc++.

But honestly if you're using a `regex` to strip duplicate white space, ["Now you have two problems"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems)

A better solution could use [`adjacent_find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) which [runs fine with libstdc++ as well](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/434b0317cde06029):

```
const auto func = [](const char a, const char b){ return isspace(a) && isspace(b); };

for(auto it = adjacent_find(begin(test), end(test), func); it != end(test); it = adjacent_find(it, end(test), func)) {
    *it = ' ';
    it = test.erase(next(it), find_if_not(next(it), end(test), [](const auto& i) { return isspace(i); }));
}
```

This will return the same thing your `regex` would:

> "Small text with several lines. "

But if you're going for simplicity, you could also use [`unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique):

```
test.resize(distance(test.begin(), unique(test.begin(), test.end(), [](const auto& a, const auto& b) { return isspace(a) && isspace(b); })));
```

Which will return:

> "Small text
> with several
> lines. "

Comment: It was in pipeline of regexps, so choice was somewhat natural. Thanks for pointing out `adjacent_find`, STL keeps surprise me with it's hidden treasures.

Comment: @MadRunner I would concede on that point, if you already *must* use a `regex` rolling additional functionality into it is a great decision. But I guess in this case that's going to mean using libc++ :(

Comment: @MadRunner Incidentally, I didn't want to write this bug because I didn't want my email to be public information, but if you write it up and would be willing to put the bug number in a comment here, or appended to your answer that would probably be helpful to future generations.

Comment: Is there a GCC/libstdc++ bug report for this?

Comment: @qarma Yup, the OP edited his question to say that he had added one: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70459

Answer (score 0):

Question 2 (smart way to overcome the problem)

Not really smart but... you can iterate a limited replace.

An example

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
 {
   constexpr int N = 22311;

   //std::regex r("\\s+");
   std::regex r("\\s{2,100}");

   const char* bomb2 = "Small text\n\nwith several\n\nlines.";

   std::string test(bomb2);

   for (auto i = 0; i < N; ++i)
      test += " ";

   std::string out = test;

   std::size_t  preSize;

   do
    {
      preSize = out.size();

      out = std::regex_replace(out, r, " ");
    }
   while ( out.size() < preSize );

   std::cout << '\"' << out << '\"' << std::endl;

   return 0;
 }
```