# Regex matching takes forever

Tags: c++, regex, linux, c++11

I have a simple text file of about 30 lines, as follows:

```
A 45.0 X 250.0  
Y -23.8
A 22.0 X -1016.0
Y 4.9
L 0
M 16.1 T 0 N 0

...etc...
...etc...
```

Every line contains 1 to 3 pairs of a capital letter and a float. All separators are spaces.
I then made a program which checks every single line of that file with this simple regex:

```
std::ifstream stream;
try
{
    stream.open("/ArchivioProgrammi/p1.prg", std::ios::in);
}
catch(std::exception& e)
{
    std::stringstream st;
    st << "Error opening file.\nError:   " << e.what();
    throw MyLoadException(st.str());
}
std::string line;
unsigned int lineCount = 0;

while(std::getline(stream, line))  //  Per ogni linea del file estraggo fino a 6 token
{
    if(line.length() == 0) continue;

    /***  This "if" hangs indefinitely!!  ***/
    if(!std::regex_match(line, std::regex("([A-Z] [\\-\\+]?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?)( [A-Z] [\\-\\+]?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?){0,2}")))
    {
        std::stringstream st;
        st << "Line #" << lineCount << " is invalid.";
        throw MyLoadException(st.str());
    }

    //  Tokenize the line and do something with the tokens...

    ++lineCount;

}

if(stream.eof())
{
    stream.close();
}
```

Whenever the control reaches the `if`, the programs hangs forever! Unresponsive interface, no errors, no `false` or `true`!  Why?

I'm developing with KDevelop under OpenSuse latest version.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Matching a regular expression is not trivial. It taking a long time is something you should expect..

Comment: @JesperJuhl That does not agree with my experience using regexes.

Comment: @melpomene "long time" being "multiple milliseconds".

Comment: @JesperJuhl He said it hangs his program indefinitely.

Comment: I see nothing fishy about the regex; no loops, no ambiguities, no potentially overlapping matches.

Comment: @eros, try with this regex instead `^(?:[A-Z] \S+ ?){1,3}$`

Comment: `std::regex` can be quite expensive to create as the create a FSM.  What happens if you move the creation of the regex out of the if statement and just pass it to `std::regex_match`?

Comment: Raw string might simplify the regex: `R"(([A-Z] [\-\+]..)"`

Comment: So you have a problem.  You think, "I know, I can solve it with a regex!".  Now you have two problems; the original problem, and you are using regex.

Comment: See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36304204/%D0%A1-regex-segfault-on-long-sequences), try using `-stdlib=libc++`

Comment: @FedericoPiazza   with your try, I get  SIGABRT  regex_error

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew   I get "unrecognized command line option" when inserting your flag in the KDevelop project configuration.

Comment: @Jarod42: Neither the `-` nor the `+` require escaping at all, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: `-` might need escaping inside `[]`, but indeed not here. I have just replace first part of OP regex in fact... would be relevant only for `\.`...

Comment: @Jarod42: Not if it's at the start or end of the character class.

Comment: `std::regex re(R"((?:[A-Z] [-+]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)? ?){1,3})");  
std::smatch matches;   
std::regex_match(line, matches, re);  
if(matches.size() != 1)  
{  
 ....  
}`      
   

Still, the creation of this regex takes forever. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using raw string it works like a charm.
Even if I have never understood the meaning of beginning such strings with both double quotes *and a parenthesis*....

How coud I have written the regex in a shorter form?

Comment: How coud I have written the regex in a shorter form?

Answer (score 0):

Try confirming that your regex pattern is correct by testing it online (e.g. [online Regex tester](http://regex101.com)). You may also want to consider iterating through the input file line by line using regex on one line at a time. Or just not use regex at all.

Comment: I'm not sure of what yo're advising.  Going line by line? That's exactly what I said I'm doing!

Comment: Sorry - I see from your code that you are reading line by line. I also tested your regex pattern and it does find matches in your text file. Start commenting out your code (e.g. if(!std::regex_match) until you find what is making it hang. Hope you solve it.