# How to compile C/C++ file dynamically from C#

Tags: c#, c++, compilation

I want to compile C/C++ file dynamically from C# code.

For example I have a c++ file (test.cpp)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    cout << "Hello, world, from Visual C++!" << endl;
}
```

Here is the C# code where i want to compile the *.cpp file.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var start = new ProcessStartInfo();

        start.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe";
        start.Arguments = @" /EHsc D:\test\test.cpp /out:D:\test\test.exe";

        start.UseShellExecute = false;
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        string StandardOutput = "";

        using (var process = Process.Start(start))
        {
            // Could be useful to eventually track error
            using (var reader = process?.StandardOutput)
            {
                StandardOutput += reader?.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(StandardOutput);
    }
}
```

When the code is executed it gives the following error.

Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27026.1 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'o' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
test.cpp
D:\test\test.cpp(1): fatal error C1034: iostream: no include path set

[image]

Comment: The error message tells you that you have not set the include path for the compiler. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931652/fatal-error-c1034-windows-h-no-include-path-set

Comment: This won't solve the problem at hand, but you might want to consider an alternative to hardcoding the paths if possible.

Comment: You could set the environment variables with: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.environmentvariables?view=netframework-4.7.2 or add additional arguments to to your `start.Arguments =` for the include and linker paths.

Answer (score 1):

try to first run

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat
```

---

For executing both scripts at the same time, you can use below approach

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat\"\n\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe\" /EHsc D:\test\test.cpp /out:D:\test\test.exe");
```

For more information: [Check This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27384870/1118978)

Comment: How can I run it from the C# code, can you please show some code.

Comment: Thanks, but the code you have shared is not working, I am getting the following error. "'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." @Simonare