# Automate Send Mail Process in Windows Batching

Tags: windows, batch-file

Manually, I can do the following from Windows CMD,

```
telnet smtp.server 25
MAIL FROM:<Test@domain.com>
RCPT TO:<Test2@domain.com>
data
message
.
quit
```

And It's working Normally but I am trying to automate this via windows batching, IT's easy to do this via shell Scripting on Linux, But in windows batching I found many troubles to make this kind of interactive scripts.

Do you've Suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You may directly store your lines above in a **text file** (*not* a Batch one) and then use an interesting trick in order to execute them:

```
cmd < theFile.txt
```

Previous line open a cmd.exe session that get its input from the given file instead of the keyboard. You may read further details about this method at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320578/how-to-run-batch-script-with-out-using-bat-extention/13337597#13337597).

Comment: This means that `telnet` program does not read its input from Stdin in the usual way. Bad luck... :/

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the Windows `telnet` utility cannot be scripted. There are solutions, but they're ugly. See https://serverfault.com/questions/41919/can-the-windows-telnet-client-be-scripted.