# how can I run a script without an extension?

Tags: wsh

Say I have a file on my desktop that doesn't have extension, but contains some code (say Batch or VBS). 
Can I run this code without adding an extension to the file? 
I was personally thinking about using powershell to pass an extension to wscript.exe, but this turned out to be somewhat impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For VBS\JS scripts you need to specify engine with `//E` switch.

Examples:

- If file `xxx` contains VbScript code: `wscript //E:VBScript c:\xxx`
- If file `xxx` contains JavaScript code: `wscript //E:JScript c:\xxx`

For batch files, it's not so easy. There is some workarounds, but they're somewhat limited: [How to run batch script with out using *.bat extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320578/how-to-run-batch-script-with-out-using-bat-extention)