# Use cmd to run batch code

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Hi I need to run a file witch contains batch code from cmd and is not a batch file.

I have tested    `cmd < test.bob`
and it gets one line in and ends

I did this before but I don't remember the code i think it was    `cmd /v:on < test.bob`
or    `cmd /E:on < test.bob`
please help me

note please don't tell me to change the extension

Comment: Is there non-batch data in test.bob, or is it just a renamed .bat file? And if it is a renamed batch file, why not just change the extension?

Comment: It is it just a renamed .bat file i cant use .bat i need to use .JJIS I used .bob in the post

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why can't you change the extension?

Comment: i did it before i want to do it again

Comment: As long as you don't care what it outputs to the screen and you don't want it to be even remotely interactive, you can use `cmd /k<test.bob`

Comment: oops i did that to it did not work thanks anyway

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work?" I just did it and as long as you don't need the user to input anything, the code runs correctly. (Note that if you're getting a `More?` response, you need to press enter after the last line.)

Comment: it does work in batch but not in command line type in in run on windows xp it wont work

Comment: I don't know what you're doing wrong, but it totally works via the command prompt: http://i.imgur.com/mlqLntX.png

Comment: my code  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwQfG2vV_VfvNXNzQ190Yzg5ZU0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Press enter after `.bat`. There _must_ be an empty line at the very end of the file or it won't work.

Comment: nope https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwQfG2vV_VfvU1Y2VHFQQlVDNlE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You've got spaces in your path name. Put that line in quotes.

Comment: thank you that did work try this https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwQfG2vV_VfvZ0tlVmZRQXJVbnc/view?usp=sharing. can you post your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that this way:

```
cmd < test.bob
```

If you use Delayed Expansion in your "Not Batch file", use this:

```
cmd /V:ON < test.bob
```

However, there are several differences that apply to the "Not Batch file"; the most important one is that the following *Batch file features* don't works in the "Not Batch file":

- Access to Batch file parameters via %1 %2 ... and execution of SHIFT command.
- Execution of GOTO command.
- Execution of CALL :NAME command (internal subroutine).
- Execution of SETLOCAL/ENDLOCAL commands.

The complete description of the way to do this ("Execute a text file with no .BAT extension as a Batch file") is described at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320578/how-to-run-batch-script-with-out-using-bat-extention/13337597#13337597), with examples and recommendations.