# How to run file with different extension as BAT file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Imagine having text file with custom (not reserved) extension

```
myFileSayHello.myExtension
```

Which contains for example:

```
@echo on
@echo "Hello"
@pause
```

*How can I run it using cmd as bat file?*

```
cd %pathToFile%    
start myFileSayHello.myExtension
```

Code above does not working and explorer asking to select program to open `.myExtension`.

**How can I do that `.myExtension` will behave like `.bat` inside cmd ?**

Comment: `cmd /k < Anyfile.ext`

Comment: @Noodles, I guess this is going to fail for several commands (like `for`), because the `.ext` file is not parsed as a batch file but as a typed command lines...

Comment: Yet is can do everything a batch file can except for %errorlevel%. I don't use batch files. I copy and paste lines.

Comment: No, it can't -- see the [`for` variable references](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) with one or two `%` signs for `cmd` and batch files, respectively; or `setlocal`/`endlocal`, which will be totally ignored, or `exit /B`, labels...

Comment: I can confirm that it does what I except. Can you, Noodles, post an answer that I can mark as working for others. Thanks.

Comment: @aschipfl: At [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320578/how-to-run-batch-script-with-out-using-bat-extention/13337597#13337597) there is a detailed description of the differences that happen in a text file executed this way vs. a real .BATch file.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way in the command prompt that requires administrative privileges:

```
assoc .myExtension=myExtensionfile
ftype myExtensionfile="%1" %*
set "PATHEXT=%PATHEXT%;.myExtension"
setx PATHEXT "%PATHEXT%;.myExtension"

cd /D "%pathToFile%"

myFileSayHello
```

The modified `PATHEXT` is stored for the current user's context, unless you append `/M` to the `setx` command line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  For some reason Java doesn't allow me to clear %temp% folder (even self-created txt files).

Comment: Sorry, I cannot follow you...