# Execute commands on windows command prompt from a text file

Tags: batch-file, command, tesseract

My text file has all the commands written down that have to be executed(one command on each line). How do I request the windows command prompt to read each command from this text file and execute it? I did try to research on this problem and the solution that I got was using batch files. I do not know what are batch files. Please help.

All the ten commands in the text file are:

```
tesseract.exe 1.png ../newfile/1 -l eng
tesseract.exe 2.png ../newfile/2 -l eng
tesseract.exe 3.png ../newfile/3 -l eng
tesseract.exe 4.png ../newfile/4 -l eng
tesseract.exe 5.png ../newfile/5 -l eng
tesseract.exe 6.png ../newfile/6 -l eng
tesseract.exe 7.png ../newfile/7 -l eng
tesseract.exe 8.png ../newfile/8 -l eng
tesseract.exe 9.png ../newfile/9 -l eng
tesseract.exe 10.png ../newfile/10 -l eng
```

Comment: `cmd < theFile.txt` See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13337597/778560)

Comment: you need only one line for this: `for /L %i in (1,1,10) do tesseract.exe %i.png ../newfile/%i -l eng` (for usage in a batch file, use `%%i` instead of `%i`)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in a for loop.

```
For /f "delims=" %%i in (filename.txt) do "%%i"
```

It basically loops through the file. `delims=` changes standard delimiters being whitespace, so it grabs the entire line instead.

To create the batch file. Open `notepad.exe` and add the above code. Save the file in the same directory as your text file as some name and add a extension of `.cmd`

Alternatively, you can just rename the current text file to an extension of `.cmd` and run it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned at the foot of Gerhard's answer, you could use `Ren`ame:

```bat
Copy "file.txt" tmp.cmd>Nul
Call tmp.cmd && Del tmp.cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Save your command in a text file. Save that file with '.cmd'
   extension. Example: myfilename.cmd.
2. Now, go to your desired command prompt window i.e. PowerShell, GoogleCloud SDK, etc.
3. Go to the directory which contains the above-saved file (i.e. myfilename.cmd).
4. Type the name of the file in the command and hit enter.
5. The command contained in that file will run.

Pro: With this, you can run as many long commands as you desire without worrying about the character limit for a command that command prompt has.